# Change the parameter type

Tags: java, android

I created a new method to change activities because I don't want to repeat code.

Everytime that a textview is clicked, I call this method:

```
globalMethods.ChangeActivity(txtSignup,InitialActivity.this,RegistrationActivity.class);
```

Method code:

```
public static void ChangeActivity(TextView target, final Activity currentActivity, final Class<?> nextActivity){

        target.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity, nextActivity);
                currentActivity.startActivity(intent);  
                currentActivity.overridePendingTransition(R.drawable.push_down_in,R.drawable.push_down_out);
            }
        });

    }
```

Now I would like to adapt this code to every type of objects, like buttons.

Can you guys give me any suggestion of how can I check if the user clicked at a textview or a button, and send it to the parameter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this instead, as all widgets are inherit `View` class:

```
public static void ChangeActivity(View target, final Activity currentActivity, final Class<?> nextActivity){

        target.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity, nextActivity);
                currentActivity.startActivity(intent);  
                currentActivity.overridePendingTransition(R.drawable.push_down_in,R.drawable.push_down_out);
            }
        });

    }
```